# Missing some dark posts in list of posts facebook graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am facing a problem with retrieving dark post via Facebook graph API. 
For example, I call request to particular dark post like this:

`/123456789_111112222223333?fields=is_hidden,is_expired,is_published,message,created_time`

I receive the requested object like this:

```
{
  "is_hidden": true,
  "is_expired": false,
  "is_published": false,
  "message": "Some message",
  "created_time": "2019-03-22T13:35:10+0000",
  "id": "123456789_111112222223333"
}
```

But when I call request for promoted_posts: 
`123456789/promotable_posts?fields=is_hidden,created_time&include_hidden=true&is_published=false&include_inline=true`
I receive an empty array of objects. When I change parameter is_published into true, I receive list of posts, with created time before and after that post.

How can I receive all dark posts for the page? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: This may sound stupid: try again? I'm moderately certain I was having exactly this problem a couple of weeks ago, but today it seems to be working fine. I'm hoping the API was having a glitchy moment, or I'm losing my sanity.
Also worth noting that in more recent (>=2.9) versions of the API a greater level of permission (CREATE_ADS) seems to be required.

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy!

```
/{page-id}/ads_posts?include_inline_create=true
```

Gives you all ads posts (Dark Posts also included)